# How would I add this header to Rails 3 ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I'm trying to get SendGrid setup for my app and one thing I want to do is let SendGrid categorize the email.

To do that, they say to add this header to outgoing email: `X-SMTPAPI: {"category": "Category Name"}`

So, how would I add that header to an ActionMailer method (it'd be added to each method since each category would be unique)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add it directly to the headers hash for the mail object

headers: { 'X-SMTPAPI': {"category": "Category Name"}}

I might have munged a quote but the point is you have full access to the headers off the mail message -- heck, that's what to: and subject: are -- email headers